# How to detect UIWebview drop in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, ios11

I have a `UIWebView`. I am trying to implement `ios11` drag and drop feature. When I drag item from Safari and drop it in my `UIWebView`, I want to know which delegate method will get called. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think, in mobile device -- 1. Safari may not allows drag operation  -- 2. Drag operation can't switch two apps with each other. Please share any reference you have seen this operation ever with mobile device web broswers

Comment: I am trying in iPad pro @Krunal

Answer (score 3):

Most of the functionality of UIWebview is implemented in an undocumented class called UIWebBrowserView. It is that view which has its 'interactions' property set and the delegate for those interactions is set to that same UIWebBrowserView.

Depending on your needs, there are 3 options to detect the drop:

1) You could use javascript in the content of the web view to detect the drop. This would looks something like:

```
document.addEventListener('drop', function() {
     // Drop detected
} ) ;
```

2) You could disable the drop interactions in the UIWebBrowserView. That will allow them to propagate up into one of the containing views, and you can add your own interactions there. That would look like:

```
webView.scrollView.subviews[0].interactions = @[] ;
```

Once you've done that, the you can create your own interactions and add them to the container view:

```
 UIDropInteraction *dropInteration = [[UIDropInteraction alloc]initWithDelegate:myController] ;
 [webView addInteraction:dropInteration] ;
 webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES ;
```

You would then implement the UIDropInteractionDelegate functionality in 'myController'

3) You could swizzle UIWebBrowserView and replace the UIDropInteractionDelegate methods with your own.

Comment: I dont think 2 and 3 would work. I am trying the first option. How can I get the dropped text or images in js?

Comment: Actually, I was able to get both '2' & '3' working, but I was not able to get '1' working because I ran into the same stumbling block as you. I was unable to determine the objects being dropped.

My javascript skills are limited, but I do suspect it's possible to get information about the dropped objects using javascript.  I just don't know how to do it.

For my part, I settled on '2' as it is one line to disable the default behavior for drops. I was even able to retain the default drag interaction by checking the classes of the existing interactions and only removing the dropInteraction.

Comment: Yes I am trying the 2nd option you suggested. I am also getting the data on perform drop. Is it possible to move the cursor when I drag over the UIWebView?. Have you done it?. And also how do you animate the content being dropped?

Comment: Yes. The cursor is an issue. The swizzling method ('3') handles that for you, but it is possible to do on your own with '2'. In the sessionDidUpdate, I create a separate view to mimic the cursor and sets that views origin to something based on [session locationInView:self]. The 'dropProposal' you return from the delegate should have '.precise' set to YES. When the performDrop is called I set the real cursor (using javascript) to the range based on the position of my custom fake cursor view.  I'm not yet animating the content drop, so I can't answer that.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you tell me how to do method swizzling here (option 3)?. Can you post some code.

Answer (score 2):

[UIDragInteractionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidraginteractiondelegate) & [UIDropInteractionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidropinteractiondelegate) protocols are what you're looking for.

Check this out as well: [How to Drop Images in UIViewController with UIDropInteraction (Ep 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRrztQQGnGk)

Comment: This one is for normal UIView drag and drop.